# enter multiple mail ids and separated by ';' and validation in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I was creating a form. Certian fields of the form  store all of those IDs to a single field separated by a comma or semicolon. how to send the mail id's for email validation which is providing by flex by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the values in the field (using a standard string split) on comma (or whatever separator you decide to use), and then use the email validator for each of the splitted string (email Ids).

Answer (score 0):

This is in addition to the answer marked as correct above:

https://wimdeblauwe.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/validation-of-multiple-email-addresses-in-flex/

> For our flex application, I had a ‘cc’ field that could handle
>   multiple email addresses. When adding validation, I first used the
>   standard EmailValidator class. However, this would not work as soon as
>   you want to add multiple email addresss, like:
>   foo@company.com;bar@company.com